# Missed to reply notice

Tags: contract-law, breach-of-contract, notice

Somebody sued me for breach of contract. The case is in circuit court. The judge gave a trial date. However, plaintiff sent me an updated complaint copy after that. I thought it's just an update. I didn't do anything. After exactly 30 days, I got a motion notice that he filed against me for default decision. I am in the state of TN.

Motion date is after 2 days. What are my options?

1 - Should I submit a reply to motion or just go on motion date to verbally explain?

2 - What to do about the notice? Should I also prepare a reply to the updated complaint?

3 - Could court simply follow the law and give a decision in his favor as I didn't reply to him within 30 days?

Comment: With respect to 1, 2 & 3, you should hire a lawyer.

Comment: The amount he sued me for is less than $1000. Lawyer would cost me more than the amount he sued me for. On more point I missed to add in the question is that he lost the case in small claim court before.

Comment: In that case, pay him.

Comment: But he lying and have no proof. He is lying and saying things about "verbal contract" that never happened. That's why he lost in small claim court as well. If I was wrong then I wouldn't mind paying my hard cash money. But I cannot pay anyone for lying about something that never happened.

Comment: BTW, what can I do for missing a reply to his notice? Is there any grace period I can request or anything?

Comment: If you want to win, hire a lawyer. If you want to minimize costs pay him. If you do neither you will lose and spend more money.

Comment: Cmon dale surely he can apply to set aside default judgment. Its inappropriate here to say his options are to hire a lawyer or give up. Unless of course, his jurisdiction doesn't allow setting aside of default judgments.

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks, are you suggesting that OP is sufficiently familiar with legal procedure that he can file a motion? It's inappropriate to suggest that there's a realistic third alternative when there isn't. Unless you think you can give him correct legal advice.

Comment: It is not necessarily true that OP would lose his case on his own, even if you would think it is likely. Judging from the information we have, OP is a layman representing himself in a small claims dispute, and the opposing party has been awarded default judgment. Though this indicates a weak understanding of legal procedure it is wholly inappropriate for anyone, acting on this information alone, to tell OP that his options are to hire a lawyer or concede the case.

Comment: Anyone practicing law knows that default judgment is a purely procedural matter, and is often set aside after application to the presiding judge, all you need to demonstrate, depending on jurisdiction, is that you have a reasonable prospect of successfully defending the claim.

Comment: I do not expect members on this site to know this, or the relevant test in OP's jurisdiction. But no member here should say with such certainty that the only two options are to hire a lawyer or pay up.

Comment: I would not object to dale changing his advice to "judging by the situation, your best option is to hire a lawyer, otherwise i think it is likely that you would lose the case". Notice the avoiding of absolutes here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from your post that (1) the plaintiff amended the complaint (i.e., what you think was "*just an update*"); (2) you did not know that you had a deadline to file responsive pleadings to that amended complaint; and (3) having missed your deadline, the plaintiff filed a motion for default judgment.

Your mention [in the comments] that the plaintiff already lost this case in small claims court suggests that the current complaint is his attempt to re-litigate matters (that is, a matter that is *res judicata*).

If this is so, you should file a response to that motion and your responsive pleadings. There you need to point out --and preferably attach evidence-- that the matter is indeed *res judicata* and that therefore the court should dismiss the case. This is not necessarily the only defense available to you in the pleadings you file but, without knowing the specifics of your matter, it is impossible to identify what else would be appropriate for you to argue.

You could just show up at the hearing for default judgment, although that is strongly discouraged. It is better that you file your response to the motion & pleadings ASAP. First, because the dynamics of the court hearing might prevent you from adequately presenting your arguments verbally (let alone having them properly assessed by the judge). And second, to ensure that the record of the case clearly reflects your arguments & evidence in the event that this goes to the appellate court.

At this point it seems obvious that you have little-to-no time to become acquainted with TN court rules, aka procedural law or rules of procedure. Same with legal theories, contract law, statutory law, and rules of evidence. But even if you are unable to search for records of other proceedings litigated in your court, you should at all times strive to present and prove your arguments *in writing and verbally* as clearly as possible so that a judge (assuming that he is not so sloppy or negligent) grasps the merits of your legal position.

Comment: If it were CA, res judica would not apply to an appeal from small claims. Without knowing TN law this answer is dangerous.

"A small claims appeal is a "trial de novo" or "new trial." This means that the case is decided by a new judge from the beginning so you have to present your case all over again."

from https://www.courts.ca.gov/1072.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's not a new case. It's an appeal to small claim court decision. Is it still the matter of res judicata?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite That site explains the notion of *appealing* a small claims ruling, which is different than filing elsewhere a new & updated complaint on a controversy that has already been adjudged in small claims. Moreover, the explanation in that website does not constitute case law. By contrast, [*Allstate Ins. Co. v. Mel Rapton, Inc.*, 77 Cal.App. 4th 901](https://www.leagle.com/decision/200024392calrptr2d1511229) reflects that *res judicata* certainly applies to CA small claims rulings. I see no case law reflecting that this would be any different in Tennessee courts.

Comment: @AJW "*It's an appeal to small claim court decision. Is it still the matter of res judicata?*" No. As I said to GeorgeWhite, appealing and re-suing are two different things. The terms of "*sued me for breach of contract*" and "*updated complaint*" in your initial post led me to think that the plaintiff was attempting to overcome *res judicata*. Fully developing your arguments (e.g., *in writing*) is still likelier to improve your chances of prevailing in circuit court, whereas by doing anything less than that you risk your arguments be considered waived if this goes to upper courts for review.

Comment: the Allstate case was an attempt at a completely new case after a small claims case was decided. That is not the same as an appeal of the small claims case which is, in CA, de novo.

Comment: Should I submit the answer to notice before motion date? Or should I carry the answer to notice with me and give to judge? Motion hearing date is on Friday. Also how can I defend in writing that why I didn't answer before? Notice did not mention I need to reply or deadline to reply the notice.

Comment: @AJW You should file in court your response ASAP (not sure how rules 6.04  & 6.05 of the [TN rules of civil procedure](https://tncourts.gov/court-rules/218) apply to responses), including a judge's copy. Also mail a copy to the plaintiff. Just bringing to the hearing your response might be futile unless the hearing is adjourned or the judge spends time in the courtroom to read your response (but see 1st paragraph of rule 5.06). Without knowing plaintiff's timing and method of service of his motion & papers, it is hard to give you any suggestions on how to defend why you missed the deadline.

Comment: Plaintiff sent the notice by registered mail on 30th July and put a motion for default judgement on 3rd of September. On some forums/webs it says that a legal notice shall have a form that contains deadline to reply or some text. However, there was nothing like that on the notice I got. Wouldn't it be in my favor? or deadline or reply requested kind of statements are not mandatory in legal notices?

Comment: @AJW I am not acquainted with TN rules and haven't looked enough in the link I posted, but in Michigan (and surely elsewhere) there is no need to give a deadline in the notice because the Michigan Court Rules provide deadlines for filing/servicing responses to a motion; namely, 9 days prior to the hearing or 7 if serviced in person. Typically responses are not mandatory unless it relates to matters such as discovery requests, requests for admissions, or *to show good cause*. Regardless, for purposes of the record on appeal, filing a belated response is better than filing nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! you helped a lot. Submitting a belated answer was better than not answering. Judge dismissed the motion and set the trial date. For others, judges are not bad, they are also humans, they will understand. So better submit an answer even if you are late.